# How to mock a new Object Creation in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Below is the code to be mocked:

```
private MultivaluedMap<String, Object> addAuthorizationAndCorrelationIdHeader(MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders) {
    if(httpHeaders == null)
        httpHeaders = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();

        String token = new JSONWebToken().getUserInfo().getToken("SYSTEM", "JobScheduler");
}
```

How to mock new JSONWebToken() part?

Answer (score 3):

You should create some kind of JSONTokenFactory like:

```
public class JSONWebTokenFactory {
    public JSONWebToken creaateWebToken() {
        return new JSONWebToken(); 
    }
}
```

Then pass the instance of the factory to the class your're testing. Now you can pass a mock of JSONTokenFactory in tests.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. You use mocking frameworks such as PowerMock or Mockito that allow for mocking calls to `new`
2. You **avoid** doing `new` calls in your production code. Instead, you use dependency injection; for example by using a factory (as in the answer you already got), or by passing in such objects via constructors.

Long story short: using `new` can lead to "hard to test" code. The real answer is to learn how to create **testable** code; a good starting point are these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79).

Answer (score -1):

You can use spy `org.mockito.Mockito.spy`. it will look something like this..

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class YourTestClass {

@Test
public void yourTestCase() {
    JSONWebToken jwt = spy(new JSONWebToken());
    UserInfo mockUserInfo = mock(UserInfo.class);
    when(jwt.getUserInfo()).thenReturn(mockUserInfo);
}
}
```

Comment: Still throws null pointer:
Because it gets evaluated inside this (new JSONWebToken().getUserInfo()) which returns it as null

Comment: make sure that you have added `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` before class